# Why does .get() work in the scenario where I am assigning a key a value in a table vs where I am looking for a value inside a table?

Tags: python

I am working with the .get() method in Python.

To my understanding the .get() method takes in two parameters.

1. A key for the given hash table
2. A default value given that key does not exist in the table.

and returns either the value of the key if it exists or the default value otherwise

In the scenario below the function returns an error:

```
def containsDuplicate(self, nums: List[int]) -> bool:
    lookup = {}
    for n in nums:
        if lookup.get(lookup[n], False) != True:
            lookup[n] = True
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

KeyError: 1
if lookup.get(lookup[n], False) != True:

While this second does not return any errors:

```
def isAnagram(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
    mapS, mapT = {}, {}
    if len(s) == len(t):
        for i in range(len(s)):
            mapS[s[i]] == mapS.get(s[i], 0)
            mapT[t[i]] = mapT.get(t[i], 0)
        for i in range(len(s)):
            if mapS[s[i]] != mapT.get(t[i], 0):
                return False
        return True
    elif: Return False
```

The two uses of the .get() function for simplicity of reading:

```
if lookup.get(lookup[n], False) != True:

mapS[s[i]] == mapS.get(s[i], 0)
mapT[t[i]] = mapT.get(t[i], 0)
```

Comment: Your problem is that inside the call to `lookup.get(...)` you're asking for `lookup[n]`, which triggers the KeyError exception of `n` does not exist in `lookup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def containsDuplicate(self, nums: list[int]) -> bool:
    lookup = {}
    for n in nums:
        # if lookup.get(n, False) != True:
        # P.S. use "is" when using None, True, or False.
        # Ex)
        # if lookup.get(n, False) is not True:
        # if lookup.get(n, False) is False:
        # However, in this case a more pythonic way is:
        if not lookup.get(n, False):
            lookup[n] = True
        else:
            return True
    return False
```

The syntax of `dict.get(key, default)` is:

`dict.get(key, default)`

Where:

`key` is the KEY of the item you are looking for. For example, in the dictionary `{0:1, 1:1, 2:1, 3: 2}`, the key of the value `2` is `3`.

`default` is what is returned if the key is not found. For example, in the previous dictionary, `dict.get(4, False)` would return `False` because the key `4` is not in the dictionary.

Another way to think about it is that `dict.get(n, default)` is the same as:

```py
try:
    return dict[n]
except KeyError:
    return default
```

Your code was passing in the value that you were looking for, and when the key wasn't found,  it raised an error.

Basically, it was trying to find the non-existant value to pass in as the key to the `dict.get()` function, which is why it raised an error.